# Problems upgrading Android Studio to Java 1.9 for Roboelectric

Tags: android, android-studio, robolectric

I am trying to use Robolectric 4.3.1 for testing

```
I get the error:  java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: failed to configure com.example.loginTest: Package targetSdkVersion=30 > maxSdkVersion=29
```

So because of that I downloaded JDK 1.9 and changed the JDK location in the "Project Structure" dialog.  I also changed my app/build.gradle file:

```
android {
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_9
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_9
    }
...
```

When I do that, then nothing compiles at all.  It's almost as if the Android SDK is not working:

I get errors such as:

```
class file for android.view.ViewGroup not found
package android.content does not exist
package android.widget does not exist
etc.
```

Comment: Robolectric 4.x doesn't support Android SDK 30. See https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric/releases

Comment: Thank you!  I read the error message incorrectly, I thought it was saying I needed SDK 30 and I only had 29.